# Find a string in an array, then keep the next 5 lines

Tags: powershell

Afternoon all,

I have a config file that's dynamic based on the user. What I need to do is find a specific line in this config file, then keep the next five lines.

The config file looks something like

```
[default]
entry 1 = lkjkljok
entry 2 = hjghgj
entry 3 = b12121
entry 4 = jhkjfhke3

[new]
entry 1 = 1e2h3323
entry 2 = jkljlknww
entry 3 = 5nkjnkj
entry 4 = fveeeef
```

So my file my contain several instances of [xxxx], but I'll always want the one called new and the 4 lines after. Then nothing else.

Any ideas? I've not got much further than:

```
 gc |?{ $- -like "new" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show lines after your match, use `-Context`:

```
Select-String -path yourfile.txt -pattern "new" -Context 0,5
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest this I would recommend that you add the logic to use the `-Context` data as well since it is not obvious at first.

Comment: The command will return a MatchInfo object. Let's say it is assigned to variable `$m`, then the captured line ("[new]") will be `$m.Line` and the others lines will be reachable with `$m.Context.DisplayPostContext`. Looks like pattern "^\\[new\\]\s*$" would better fit, else entry lines with new in their value will be matched too.

Comment: You're a legend. The fact this wasn't complex at all makes me doubt myself as a decent PS scripter!

Comment: Using powershell makes me wince after using Linux for 20 years